# If the salt is blank from config.php then what mechanism cakephp used to store password?

Tags: cakephp, hash, passwords, md5, cakephp-2.0

In CakePHP config.php the salt is blank `''` , so during saving password which mechanism cakephp use to produce password?

Which core file contains that procedure to generate hashed/md5 password?

I think it uses something like `Security::hash(password);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search for ".salt" in the core files you should be able to find out that it is used in several places like so:

```
$check = Security::hash(serialize($fieldList) . $unlocked . Configure::read('Security.salt'));
```

(SecurityComponent)

and so:

```
$this->key = Configure::read('Security.salt');
```

(CookieComponent)

So an empty salt would simply have the affect of "no salt" for saving passwords.
although this can have sideeffects with cookies. An empty key might cause trouble.

Why would you want to omit the salt here, anyway?

Comment: A salt value from `config.php` gets warning when the home page loads.

Comment: So for an empty salt, does cakephp just hash it? And what is the content of that `Security::hash(..)` function?

Comment: just look into the code. it's public and no secret (/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/). but either way, it is highly recommended to NOT leave it blank.